# How to convert this LINQ to Entities query into 'Method Syntax' instead of 'Query Syntax'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following 2 EF models:

```
public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RuleValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<Exclusion> Exclusions { get; set; }
}

public class Exclusion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey( "RuleId" )]
    public Rule Rule { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query the database to return a List but only where there isn't a related record in the Exclusions table, based on the related RuleId, and for the specified ApplicationId and SiteId. Ultimately, taking into account any Application/Site specific exclusions, so as to not include those Rules in the results that I return.

I've been able to achieve this so far using the following query:

```
IQueryable<Rule> query =
                        from r in context.Rule
                        where r.IsActive && !( from e in context.Exclusion
                                               where e.ApplicationId == applicationId &&
e.SiteId == siteId
                                               select e.RuleId )
                               .Contains( r.Id )
                        select r;
```

I always use Method Syntax everywhere else and for consistency would prefer not to have just this one method that uses Query Syntax, but I've not been able to get the same thing working using Method Syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you navigating to the exclusions for this rule (r.Exclusions) instead of all Exclusiong (context.Exclusions) and then filtering on the current rule? This is very backward

If i understood your requirement right you should do:

```
var query = context.Rule
     .Where(r=>r.IsActive)
     .Where(r=>!r.Exclusions.Any(e=>e.ApplicationId == applicationId && e.SiteId == siteId);
```

Comment: I tried this approach as per your code but it was returning incorrect results, but when I changed it so where wasn't two .Where() clauses and instead used .Where(r=>r.IsActive && !r.Exclusions.Any(etc.)) then I started getting the results back I expected. Perfect, thanks! I'm sure I had tried this approach before resorting to the Query syntax but I must have got it slightly wrong! Thanks again.

Comment: .Where(x).Where(y) is equal to .Where(x && y). You should be getting the same results

Answer (score 0):

Directly translating:

```
IQueryable<Rule> query = context.Rule
    .Where(r => r.IsActive && !context.Exclusion
        .Where(e => e.ApplicationId == applicationId && e.SiteId == siteId)
        .Select(e => e.RuleId)
        .Contains(r.Id)
    )
    .Select(r => r);
```

But you can of course omit the select with the identity function (just as the compiler probably would have):

```
IQueryable<Rule> query = context.Rule
    .Where(r => r.IsActive && !context.Exclusion
        .Where(e => e.ApplicationId == applicationId && e.SiteId == siteId)
        .Select(e => e.RuleId)
        .Contains(r.Id)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var query =   context.Rule.Where(r => r.IsActive && !context.Exclusion.Any(e => e.ApplicationId == applicationId && e.SiteId==siteId && r.Id==e.RuleId))
```

Comment: Please try to improve your answer by adding some explanation to go along with your code and why you believe it provides a solution to the problem.